# find('all') retrieving only the 'id' field

Tags: arrays, find, cakephp-1.3

I am beating my head on my desk.  I have only two fields of data, yet this old version of cake I am working in (1.3) is pulling only the 'id' field into an array, and ignoring the other field ('link_txt').  My models work, as this works in other controllers.  I am trying to populate an xml sitemap and it..just...isn't working. (my sitemap doesn't show the document tree either when I view it in my browser tho it shows it if I view its source....!!!!  I posted a question [about it here earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684795/unable-to-write-xml-sitemap-in-cakephp) if anyone thinks the two are related)  I haven't got a clue what I am doing wrong!

```
<?php 
class SitemapsController extends AppController{ 

var $name = 'Sitemaps'; 
var $uses = array('Category', 'Listing', 'Article', 'Location'); 
var $helpers = array('Time', 'xml'); 
var $components = array('RequestHandler'); 

function index (){  
    Configure::write ('debug', 2);
    $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml'); 
    $this->viewPath = 'xml';
    $this->layoutPath = 'xml';
    $a=$this->Article->find('all');
    $this->set('static', $a);


}
} 
?>
```

If I `print_r($static)` in my index.ctp file, I get my 'id' data, but not my 'link_txt' field data.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Article] => Array ( [id] => 3 ) ) [1] => Array ( [Article] => Array ( [id] => 4 ) ) )
```

I'd love it if it is something I'm just derping over.  Anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: BTW I bumped my debug mode up to 2 to see if I could get any cake messages (i read that it can destroy xml), but it didn't help anyways....

Comment: Try removing 'Article' from the $uses array.

Comment: could you explain why I would want to do this? (BTW, it is happening on every model I search, I used only Article in my code above for brevity's sake here.)

Answer (score 0):

$this->Article->find('all',**Null**);